# eclipse android res folder warning

Tags: android, eclipse

im new to java (and android for that matter)and recently i got tons of errors on png,mp3 files in my res folder which i didnt have for weeks before . I aslo got random errors in my class files out of nowhere even though I did not update my SDK when that happened.

Comment: put your file name and it must have all small letter

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse throws unwanted error and warning some times because of auto scripting. Some ways to rectify errors and warnings are,

1. Try to do project clean (Eclipse Toolbar->Project->Clean)
2. Fix Your project Properties (Your Project rightclick -> Android
   Tools -> Fix Project Properties)

If Nothing change just Restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The file name must contain only [a-z0-9_.]. You must not include any capital letter in Res name.
You can always see error in error/problem window.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall eclipse.

The reason for this error is unknown to me. Do remember to save your workspace folder before you proceed to uninstalling.